# How to retrieve value from table value Redis Lua script

Tags: redis, lua

I am trying to extract a value from a json encoded string that returned from a sorted set in Redis.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'local r= redis.call("ZRANGEBYSCORE", "iprange:locations", 34625535, "+inf", "LIMIT", 0, 1); return type(r);' 0
"table"
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'local r= redis.call("ZRANGEBYSCORE", "iprange:locations", 34625535, "+inf", "LIMIT", 0, 1); return r;' 0
1) "{\"countryCode\": \"IT\", \"countryName\": \"Italy\"}"
```

I just want to extract `countryValue` from the result.

Tried `return r.countryCode;`, `return r["countryCode"];` but all of them returned `(nil)`

By the way, I alread handle this json encoded string in my app by decoding this json into data.
Just trying to delegate this simple task to Redis Lua script engine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [built-in JSON library](https://redis.io/commands/eval#cjson):

```
eval 'local  r = redis.call("ZRANGEBYSCORE", "iprange:locations", 34625535, "+inf", "LIMIT", 0, 1);
      return cjson.decode(r[1])["countryCode"];'
```

Note that `ZRANGEBYSCORE` returns an array of results, represented in Lua by a `table`. Presumably you'll want to loop over the results and extract `countryCode` for each.